# Deserializing a JSON file with c#

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

My problem is
i have this JSON file:

and i have to save it in a list but when i try to print the first element of the list I get a System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException, as if my list is empty. this is my code:

```
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();            
        Causali o = new Causali();
        List<CausaliList> lista = new List<CausaliList>();
        WebRequest causali = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://trackrest.cgestmobile.it/causali");
        WebResponse risposta = (HttpWebResponse)CreateCausaliRequest(causali).GetResponse();
        Stream data = risposta.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader Leggi = new StreamReader(data);            
        string output = Leggi.ReadToEnd();
        lista = ser.Deserialize<List<CausaliList>>(output);
        lst2.Items.Add(lista[0]);
```

and these are my two class for the saves:

```
class Causali
    {
        public int id;
        public string causaliname;
        public string identificationcode;
        public string expired;
    }
```

and

```
class CausaliList
    {
        public Causali causali;       
    }
```

can you help me solve it?

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: can you provide a sample of the value of `output` before the `Deserialize` call? (Put a breakpoint on the `Deserialize` line and grab the contents of `output` when it breaks)

Comment: Hi.. your code is fine... can you please post the Json string that you deserialize  it into!

Comment: Output has this value: {"causali":[{"id":1,"causaliname":"PERMESSI","identificationcode":"PR","expired":"2050-12-31"},{"id":2,"causaliname":"INFORTUNIO","identificationcode":"IN","expired":"2050-12-31"},{"id":3,"causaliname":"PERMESSO ESAMI","identificationcode":"PE","expired":"2050-12-31"}]}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try this as your root object:

```
public class CausaliList
{
    public List<Causali> causali { get; set; }
}
```

then deserilize your object like this:

```
lista = ser.Deserialize<CausaliList>(output);
```

finally you can access to list like this:

```
lst2.Items.Add(lista.causali[0]);
```

Note: i strongly recommend to use json.NET.

Comment: This don't work, my list still has 0 elements and i don't know why

Comment: dear @LorenzoValenti please post your output. thank you.

Comment: glad i could help.

Answer (score 2):

To deserialize the code in c#: 
Lets assume you have data in var getContent then you may use this:

```
dynamic getDesearilize = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(getContent);
```